# Is it possible to show and then close a text block with only one button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a button in HTML and want it to show and then hide a text block. Is it possible to do it using only one bottom with JavaScript? I mean that by clicking on the button a text block should appear in `<p id="text"></p>` and when you click again the text block becomes hidden. In my code, the text block only is shown but it cannot be hidden.

my code:

`<button type="button" onclick="rulesEnglish()">Rules</button>`

`<p id="text"></p>`

//js:

```
function rulesEnglish() {
  document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'text block';
}
```

Comment: Seems, you are not showing/hiding block but adding/removing content text

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question you can try this one:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function rulesEnglish(){
      var pa = document.getElementById("text");
      if (pa.style.display === "none") {
        pa.style.display = "block";
        pa.innerHTML = 'text block';//if you want write a text...
      } else {
        pa.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="rulesEnglish()">Rules</button>
    <p id="text">My Text</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```